# Making the wheel rotate in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, rotation

I have the following code for spinning a wheel with JS and CSS:

```
var prefix = (function() {
    if (document.body.style.MozTransform !== undefined) {
        return "MozTransform";
    }
    else if (document.body.style.WebkitTransform !== undefined) {
        return "WebkitTransform";
    }
    else if (document.body.style.OTransform !== undefined) {
        return "OTransform";
    }
    else {
        return "transform";
    }
}()),
    rotateElement = function(element, degrees) {
        var val = "rotate(-" + degrees + "deg)";
        element.style[prefix] = val;
        element.setAttribute("data-rotation", degrees);
    },
 spinModifier = function() {
      return Math.random() * 10 + 25;
 },
 modifier = spinModifier(),
 slowdownSpeed = 0.5,
spinWheelfn = function(amt) {
    clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
     modifier -= slowdownSpeed;
     if (amt == undefined) amt = parseInt(wheel.getAttribute('data-rotation'));
     rotateElement(wheel, amt);
     if (modifier > 0) {
        spinTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            spinWheelfn(amt + modifier);
        }, 1000 / 5);
     } else {
        modifier = spinModifier();
        /**some other code...*/
     }
};
```

It works fine in all browsers **except** for IE.

See a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/H5LKy/129/

How do I change my function so that when you click on "Spin Wheel" in IE, the wheel will spin correcty (and get the same results)?

Comment: Any luck with this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/H5LKy/130/ I added some missing semi-colons, sometimes IE complains about that. Also, it's difficult for us to see as we don't have the wheel image :)

Comment: I have attempted to help with this issue... http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/H5LKy/131/  however my Matrix calculations are wrong? can anyone expand on this?

Comment: @mattytommo the wheel image is there.

Comment: @mattytommo it is there... for some strange reason it was missing for me... it's imgur hosted. open the image in a new tab, refresh that tab, then refresh the fiddle and all is fine again.

Comment: @mattytommo that doesnt work at all in IE still :-(

Comment: If you don't care about IE older than 9, then just add `msTransform` to your prefix detection and it will work. If you do care about IE older than 9, the pragmatic solution is to just use something like [cssSandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/04/05/cross-browser-animated-css-transforms-even-in-ie/).

Comment: @thirtydot i think the idea is not to just plop some lib on top and not understand why it works.. but to gain understanding by getting an explanation of the code in play. (my opinions of this issue are biased as i've been in the chat helping Neal with this periodically throughout the day. After each new piece of code we showed him he wanted explanations so he could understand and learn! **:)**)

Comment: @rlemon: Well, `msTransform` should be added to support IE9. That's simple enough, no explanation required. If support for IE older than 9 is indeed required, the `filter: ...Matrix()` is simply a matter of understanding the maths. Reading the source code of cssSandpaper and its documentation should help with that. Also: http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/.

Comment: will do and try to come up with a solution.

Comment: Do you really want to learn a primitive technology that is required to die as soon as possible? ... I am of course talking about IE7 and IE8

Leave all the pain to someone else; use the jQuery rotate plugin:  http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: @IvanCastellanos I **do not** want to use any outside libraries. Just native javascript.

Comment: @IvanCastellanos yes, I want to learn how to do things without the need for a library

Comment: You want to learn things that are being deprecated? Even by the creators themselfs? Microsoft already dropped DXImage Transform filters support. 
Learning to use a technology that will not exist in the close future   is a waste of time and should be discouraged; and even more when there is already abstractions that can fix those old edge cases for you.

Comment: The point is that DXImage is needed for IE8 back to IE5.5 .  The question is how to make it work for all versions of IE, and there appears no other way to take care of those versions.

Comment: @Neal, Its working for me in IE9 but taking too long on Win7.

Comment: @Gene yea.... do you have a solution? :-(

Comment: i think you have to read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Just to add my 2c, I'm very much one of those people who likes to understand the nuts and bolts - It really can help when debugging the weird and wonderful stuff later on. That said, there isn't enough time to learn it all - so if I were you, I'd ask if understanding the quirks of an expiring (and universally hated) rendering engine are a good application of your time when robust libraries now exist to abstract the problem. I've hand-crafted x-browser `xmlhttprequest` library which supported pooling, but for any real app, I'd use jQuery - not least because it's better tested. Anyway, good luck

Comment: @Neal: can i ask how you are testing IE ( 3d-party software or native browser )?

Comment: @aSeptik Native browser.

Comment: @Neal: nice, so, can you go there http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/filters/matrix.htm with your IE6 browser and tell me if this sample is working for you?

Answer (score 3):

In internet explorer, use `-ms-transition` in your css and `-ms-transform` in your javascript for internet explorer. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H5LKy/136/) for the working example (Only supported from IE9 onwards, and as usual IE is crappy and parsing javascript so that's why it's terribly slow).

For IE versions lower than 9, the following code would rotate 45 degrees:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */
```

The numbers are in radians instead of degrees.

Comment: That still wouldnt work in older version of IE (going back to at least IE8)

Comment: Also even in IE9 it is not as smooth as in other browsers

Comment: Wesley -- Thanks for the update, but how do I make it rotate **not only** for 45 degrees?

Comment: I tried it in IE using my own degrees to radian method. all it did was make the wheel bigger... http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/H5LKy/168/show/

Comment: Convert radians to degrees. `degrees = radian * 180 / pi`, or the other way around `radians = degrees / 180 * pi`

Comment: Nope, that still does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/H5LKy/176/ just makes it bigger and smaller in IE

Comment: Friends, a rotation matrix will have m11=cos(t), m12=-sin(t), m21=sin(t), m22=cos(t), where t is the rotation angle CCW.  In js it will be in radians.  The numbers in the OP are what you get for 45 degrees = pi/2 radians.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend using jQuery for this, with this plugin (you don't want to have to re-invent the wheel :P, get it?):

> This is a simple plugin to allow you to rotate images (any angle)
>   directly on client side (for ex. user generated content), and animate
>   them using own functions. Main focus is to unify this behavior across
>   different browsers.
>
> Supported Browsers:
>
> - Internet Explorer 6.0 >
> - Firefox 2.0 >
> - Safari 3 >
> - Opera 9 >
> - Google Chrome

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

Comment: @Neal, then just look at the source of jqueryrotate, it has lots of `if (IE)`
@CamiloMartin, :P