# Find the value on wheel for wheel of fortune

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an image of a wheel of fortune wheel and I am trying to make so that when it spins it displays the correct amount for what it was spun to.

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/rR67s/

Many times it is correct, and other time is is wrong.

For example I spun this:

[image: 300]

And it alerted **300**, which is wrong.

How can I fix my algorithm so that it is correct 99% of the time (or 100% if it is possible)?

HTML:

```
<div id="game">
    <div id="tick">⇩</div>
    <img id="wheel" src="http://i.imgur.com/R7JYazp.png" data-rotation="0">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var Wheel = (function () {
    var wheel = document.getElementById('wheel'),
        wheelValues = [5000, 600, 500, 300, 500, 800, 550, 400, 300, 900, 500, 300, 900, 0, 600, 400, 300, -2, 800, 350, 450, 700, 300, 600],
        spinTimeout = false,
        spinModifier = function () {
            return Math.random() * 10 + 20;
        },
        modifier = spinModifier(),
        slowdownSpeed = 0.5,
        prefix = (function () {
            if (document.body.style.MozTransform !== undefined) {
                return "MozTransform";
            } else if (document.body.style.WebkitTransform !== undefined) {
                return "WebkitTransform";
            } else if (document.body.style.OTransform !== undefined) {
                return "OTransform";
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }()),
        degreeToRadian = function (deg) {
            return deg / (Math.PI * 180);
        };

    function Wheel() {};

    Wheel.prototype.rotate = function (degrees) {
        var val = "rotate(-" + degrees + "deg)";
        if (wheel.style[prefix] != undefined) wheel.style[prefix] = val;
        var rad = degreeToRadian(degrees % 360),
            filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=" + rad + ", M12=-" + rad + ", M21=" + rad + ", M22=" + rad + ")";
        if (wheel.style["filter"] != undefined) wheel.style["filter"] = filter;
        wheel.setAttribute("data-rotation", degrees);
    };

    Wheel.prototype.spin = function (callback, amount) {
        var _this = this;
        clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
        modifier -= slowdownSpeed;
        if (amount === undefined) {
            amount = parseInt(wheel.getAttribute('data-rotation'));
        }
        this.rotate(amount);
        if (modifier > 0) {
            spinTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                _this.spin(callback, amount + modifier);
            }, 1000 / 5);
        } else {
            var dataRotation = parseInt(wheel.getAttribute('data-rotation'));
            modifier = spinModifier();
            var divider = 360 / wheelValues.length;
            var wheelValue = wheelValues[Math.floor(Math.round(dataRotation % 360) / divider)];
            switch (wheelValue) {
                case 0:
                    return callback(0);
                case -1:
                    return callback("Free Spin");
                case -2:
                    return callback("Lose a turn");
                default:
                    return callback(wheelValue);
            }
        }
    };

    return Wheel;
})();    

var wheel = new Wheel;
wheel.spin(function(spinVal){
    alert(spinVal)
});
```

Full game for those who want to try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/XP9Qv/ (<-- this was updated using accepted answer)

---

The fun continues [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/28973/3163).

Comment: You think you're cool with your fancy Wheel of Fortune game? Well, it is cool... :)

Comment: @Ian Thank you ^_^ I added a link on the bottom of my OP to the full game where the `Wheel` is used.

Comment: I believe the error has to do with the javascript determining the result before the wheel has come to a complete stop, this seems to be when the error is occurring. I'll see if I can pinpoint the exact cause.

Comment: It seems like it stores the value just before it stops, so if in the time before it stops it goes to the next amount, it displays the previous amount. Not sure how to fix that though.

Comment: I'm sorry for bringing this up because it's unrelated, but I saw your `bindEvent` function (basically the same as the more general `addEvent` that many people use), which I recently found out isn't "safe" - http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/08/addevent_consid.html . The main (only) problems are in IE, with the value of `this` in the handler, and memory leakage for not unbinding when the page is left. I have a "more complete" function but it's probably not worth to post because it can be fixed by anyone...and it's not **that** important here; I just wanted to point it out

Comment: @Ian I do not code to IE's standards :-P, I do not think I use `this` in any of the event handlers either ^_^

Comment: @Neal Hey, I'm just saying :) It was interesting to learn that `attachEvent` doesn't work like you'd expect. It's just something that can be fixed to better support IE if you want/need. I end up using jQuery all the time anyways

Comment: Bahh I was _trying_ to go libraryless :-P @Ian

Comment: @Neal Oh I know, and I think that's great! And especially since you don't use `this` in the handlers, this isn't as big of an issue for you. But just in general, it was good to learn about these quirks and come up with a more complete solution, if it was ever needed

Comment: Sorry to continue being off-topic, but I'm just wondering what `return ""; return "-ms-transform";` is doing in your `prefix` IIFE.

Comment: @Ian hehe that was related to [this OP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10806007/561731). I shall remove it :-P

Comment: @Neal Ahh okay, I just didn't know if there was some weird behavior, otherwise I was confused by 2 `return` statements. Okay, I'll get back to looking at the actual code :)

Comment: Sounds like a good plan @Ian ^_^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that the arrow in the starting position is in the middle of a zone, not at the start of it. So you have a starting offset of `(360 / wheelValues.length)/2`

```
var divider = 360 / wheelValues.length;
var offset=divider/2; //half division
var wheelValue = wheelValues[Math.floor(Math.ceil((dataRotation+offset) % 360) / divider)];
```

This seems to work: when the wheel stops either at the beginning (first half) or at the end (last half) of a zone the showed value is the expected one (just about a dozen tests done)

Comment: This seems to be the same as the solution I independently came up with.

Comment: Ok. So this will work for all wheels that have a starting point in the middle of a value. Cool. And if the starting point is on an edge, my current code _should_ work, yes?

Comment: Correct, the offset would be zero

Comment: @PabloLozano ok awesome.  Now I know! I knew it _used_ to be working fine. I think bc my old wheel started on an edge lol

Answer (score 0):

```
var wheelValue = wheelValues[Math.floor(Math.ceil(dataRotation % 360) / 15)];
            switch (wheelValue) {
```

I changed this line from `round` to `ceil` and got 14 out of 14 correct results..

Comment: Out of 1000? Also try it in a for loop with refreshing it every time. I do not know if it works fully... (also idk how to check if it is correct when running in a for loop lol)

Comment: Also I updated to using `divider == 360 / wheelValue.length` (which is the same as 15 in this case)

Comment: @Neal: 360 / wheelValue.length, I hope!

Comment: @DevlshOne I just had a test **fail** with your answer.... Sorry :-( (it was on my 3rd try)

Comment: Well, you have the exact diameter of the wheel, each of the 24 sections is of equal size, so if you use the wheelValues array, you can say that Slot[0] - Slot[24] = WheelValue[0], Slot[25] - Slot[49] = WheelValue[1], then just see exactly what point on the wheel is pointing north and extrapolate it from the Slot array, right?